# How to transition an html canvas element from a looping preloader to the rest of the animation

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I made an animation that transitions from the loading icon to something else. I'd like to loop through certain keyframes whilst the page is loading, and when the page is loaded up continue with the rest of the animation. I have no idea how to do that and would appreciate some help.

Comment: Allow me to suggest you to kindly provide examples of what you have tried so far. A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Try to use `window.onload = function() { ... }`

Comment: Or better `window.addEventListener('load', function() { ... })`.

Answer (score 0):

I think to achieve this you just need to put the following into the `<head>` element of your page:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        // here your code to show the rest of the animation
    });
</script>
```

When the page loads, the code from the header runs first. So, it's a good place to set up a function, that will handle the end of page loading.